# How to draw random points inside an ellipse?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, geometry

I want to fill this ellipse with count random points inside it any help I'd be glad.

What algorithm of actions?

Comment: You can draw random points inside a box around the ellipse, you keep them if they fall inside the ellipse, otherwise, you discard them. Stop when you got 30 points inside the ellipse

Comment: Or, you pick a random x value in the domain, get the corresponding y = f(x). Repeat 30 times.

Comment: 1. Generate 30 random points inside Ellipse area

1.1 Generate random point inside rectangle containing the ellipse. Let's say ellipse is AxB size, so you generate a point inside rectangle x:[0,A], y:[0,B]
1.2 Filter out a point if it is not inside ellipse. Check (x/A)^2 + (y/B)^2 < 1 - if false, then the point is out and should be discarded.
1.3 Do this in a loop as much times until you collect 30 valid points

2. Plot them

Comment: Why do you specify a rotation angle equal to π ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate uniformly distributed points inside ellipse, use [approach developed for disk](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html) and scale coordinates with needed ratio:

```
   generate two random values
r = A * sqrt(random(0..1))
fi = 2 * Pi * random(0..1)
  and point in ellipse with horizontal semiaxis A and vertical one B
x = center.x + r * cos(fi)
y = center.y + B / A *  r * sin(fi)
```

If ellipse is rotated, also rotate these coordinates
[image]

Comment: What is A and B in my case?

Comment: Your radiusX, radiusY (150/2 and 75/2)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It's great!!! I have a question. From what i can tell this gives points plotted in radians. I'm running a p5 script working in degrees where this code only fills in a wedge of an ellipse. I can brute force it to make a circle by changing the fi to this: fi = 114.5 * Pi * random(0..1). I'm trying to understand mathematically the reason for 114.5, instead of 2, to get a full circle in degrees. Also, is there a more understandable way to do this in degrees?

Comment: @nathan 114.5 * Pi = 360 degrees, so it would better to use `360*random(0..1)`

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sense. Very excellent, thank you.